# Where are Android Studio SDK platform files stored

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I'm having issues where Android SDK manager is not downloading the individual sdk platform files.  I found a site where I can download them from.
http://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android/build-tools/

Problem is I can't seem to figured out exactly where to put them in the sdk folder tree to get the sdk manager to recognize them.  Some searches online gave instructions on some manual installs but they all seem to be for out of date versions of the sdk manager.  At least I haven't been able to get any of them to work so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android -> sdk , there will be a build-tools folder if not create one and inside it based on your download create folders like 17.0.0(version number) and place the build tools extracted files inside it.

Comment: It got me a little closer towards getting the functionality I need.  Still getting errors about missing templates and such though.

Answer (score 0):

Default on OSX is:
~/Library/Android/sdk/